# Write large EPPlus file to stream, flushing periodically

Tags: epplus

I have to generate an Excel file that can contain the [maximum allowable rows (1,048,576)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). However, when creating the `ExcelPackage`, I have to add all of the contents first, and then save it to disk:

```cs
using (var excelStream = File.Open(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(excelStream))
{
    foreach (var widget in widgets)
    {
        // Add to spreadsheet
    }

    excelPackage.Save();
}
```

This is fine for smaller data sets, but really consumes a lot of memory when the number of rows approaches 1M.

Is there a streaming API where I can add, say, 10,000 rows at a time and then flush the output to disk so that I don't have to create the entire document in memory?

```cs
using (var excelStream = File.Open(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(excelStream))
{
    foreach (var widgetChunk in widgets.Chunk(10_000))
    {
        foreach (var widget in widgetChunk)
        {
            // Add to spreadsheet
        }
        
        // Flush to disk
    }

    excelPackage.Save();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed EPPlus, and as of today, there is no streaming API, and it is not on their roadmap.

However, I did find a suitable replacement in the [SpreadCheetah](https://github.com/sveinungf/spreadcheetah) project. Using it, I was able to generate an Excel sheet containing 1M+ rows in ~7 seconds. Definitely give it a look.